# Update property of object inside Array

Tags: javascript, html

On the click of a button the data in fruitData array gets added to another array called history.
I want the property 'bins' inside history to update whenever the properties: "kultivar", "blokNommer" and "year" match with the objects added from fruitData. (number inside bins property needs to be added together if there is a match)

for example this:

```
[
{datum: "2020-04-08", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}, 
{datum: "2020-04-08", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}
]
```

should equal this (bins: 40):

```
[
 {datum: "2020-04-08", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "40", year: "2020"}
]
```

My code:

```js
let fruitData = [{
    datum: "2020-04-08",
    kultivar: "bc",
    ha: "5",
    blokNommer: "1",
    bins: "20",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    datum: "2020-09-18",
    kultivar: "wb",
    ha: "5",
    blokNommer: "1",
    bins: "5",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    datum: "2020-03-09",
    kultivar: "bc",
    ha: "5",
    blokNommer: "1",
    bins: "20",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    datum: "2020-04-08",
    kultivar: "bc",
    ha: "5",
    blokNommer: "1",
    bins: "20",
    year: "2020"
  }
]

historyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addToHistory(fruitData)
})



function addToHistory(elements) {
  for (let elem in elements) {
    history = [...history, elements[elem]];
  }
  sortHistory()
}



function sortHistory() {
  let newHistory = [];
  history.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (newHistory.length === 0) {
      newHistory.push(item)
    } else {
      newHistory.forEach(function(itm, idx) {
        if (item.year === itm.year && item.kultivar === itm.kultivar && item.blokNommer ===
          itm.blokNommer) {
          item.bins = item.bins + itm.bins
        } else {
          newHistory.push(item)
        }
      })
    }
  })
  console.log(newHistory)
}
```

This does not give the output I am looking for. Have tried reduce method as well with no luck. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post what output are you getting after sortHistory is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the original array, and use `find()` to retrieve the existing item in the `history` array which match to `kultivar`, `blokNommer` and `year` in order to access `bins` and update it.

**Note**: It's also important to convert `bins` by `Number()` as its string in your example, and after that convert it back to `string`.

```js
const arr = [
{datum: "2020-04-08", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}, 
{datum: "2020-09-18", kultivar: "wb", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "5", year: "2020"}, 
{datum: "2020-03-09", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}, 
{datum: "2020-04-08", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}
]

const history = [];

arr.forEach(item => {
  const found = history.find(({ kultivar, blokNommer, year }) => 
    kultivar === item.kultivar && blokNommer === item.blokNommer && year === item.year)
  
  if(found) {
    found.bins = (Number(found.bins) + Number(item.bins)).toString();
  } else {
    history.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(history);
```

[find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
[Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you are changing the`itm.bins`. Array.forEach creates a copy of each element when you traverse it, so any value you change for `itm` wouldn't reflect in the actual array. Hence you are provided with the `idx` if you want to change the actual element.

Also, you are using `+` for adding strings, not integers. You need to convert it to integers first to get the desired result.

The final code should be:

```
function sortHistory(){
        let newHistory = [];
        history.forEach(function(item, index){
            if(newHistory.length === 0){
                newHistory.push(item)
            } else{
                newHistory.forEach(function(itm, idx){
                    if(item.year === itm.year && item.kultivar === itm.kultivar && item.blokNommer === 
                       itm.blokNommer){
                        newHistory[idx].bins = parseInt(item.bins) + parseInt(itm.bins);
                    }else{
                        newHistory.push(item)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        console.log(newHistory);
history = newHistory;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fruitData array not very big you can try use iterating over elements and searching `indexOf` the entire array cast to a string by `JSON.stringify` 
But if the array is large then the code is not optimal

---

```js
const fruitData = [
  {datum: "2020-04-08", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}, 
  {datum: "2020-09-18", kultivar: "wb", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "5", year: "2020"}, 
  {datum: "2020-03-09", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}, 
  {datum: "2020-04-08", kultivar: "bc", ha: "5", blokNommer: "1", bins: "20", year: "2020"}]
  
const sortHistory = (myArray) => Object.keys(myArray).reduce((accum, item) => {
  const currItem = JSON.stringify(myArray[item])
  const allArr = JSON.stringify(accum)
  return (allArr.indexOf(currItem) >= 0) ? accum : accum.concat(myArray[item])
}, [])   


console.log(sortHistory(fruitData))
```